binary(16) PK from mysql query cannot convert to integer
In my mysql query, executed from a python script, I get a column that is stored as field type binary(16).
Unfortunately, when I try to get the integer value from the column, I get
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '171099\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
(Since the value is 171099)
The code:
query = "SELECT `fieldA` FROM `table` LIMIT 1"
connection = sql.connect(user=user,password=pw,host=host,port=port,database=db)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
print(int(df['fieldA'][0]))

Where in this code, fieldA is of type binary(16)
How can I make this work?
Python version: 3.11.9
Database charset/collation: UTF8mb4/utf8mb4_0900_
I have tried:
print(int.from_bytes(df['fieldA'][0]))
But unfortunately, an incorrect number is printed.

Do you need to do it in your Python code? If you know you have an integer value, can you not cast it in the select - SELECT CAST(`fieldA` AS UNSIGNED) FROM `table` LIMIT 1? What are you actually trying to do?

is every value digits followed by trailing nul characters?  do you know why its a binary(16) type?  seems like there's something you are missing if you are expecting to always get an integer out of the field.   but you can try select substring_index(fieldA,'\0',1) fieldA from...

The solution of user1191247 works, and solves my issue in the most desired way!

@Mart just be aware it will give a mysql warning (or error if used in an update/insert with modern settings)

Remove the null bytes from the end of the value before trying to convert.
print(int(df['fieldA'][0].rstrip('\0')))

